# JBoss 6 EJB tutorial.jar

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

I was reading EJB 3.0 tutorial from JBoss site, I came across the third tutotial which is [Transactions and Security](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/security/security.html).

Here one paragraph says :

> In this particular example, the "other" domain is used. The "other"
>   domain corresponds to a **users.properties** and **roles.properties** files
>   that contain cleartext user, password, and user/role associations. If
>   you open the built **tutorial.jar** file you will see these two files in
>   there.

So i searched for the tutorial.jar in JBoss 6 directory that i extracted from zip but didn't find there.

This tutorial refers to the JBoss 4.0, so i searched for the same in JBoss 4.2 installation directory, but again didn't find there.

Can someone please help me find tutorial.jar ?

**update :**

OK, i found the properties files that used in the tutorial from [here](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/projects/ejb3/trunk/docs/tutorial/security/), but still could not find the tutorial.jar

Answer (score 0):

I find tutorial.jar file but did't get but hope this may help you ...

In your jboss root folder check to below path for roles

```
jboss-6.0.0.20100429-M3\server\default\conf\props\jbossws-roles.properties
```

and for user

```
jboss-6.0.0.20100429-M3\server\default\conf\props\jbossws-users.properties
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am looking for the tutorial.jar file which is mentioned in the tutorial web page